# Jquery Price Check calculator

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to build a price calculator. I have multiple categories with different items. Each category should show its total price value. Then the chosen items of each category have to sum up and display its overall value somewhere.

Heres a demo: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qw6stm4p/6/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').click(function() {
        var total1 = 0;
        $('.option1:checked').each(function() {
            total1 += parseInt($(this).val());
         });

         $('.total').html(total1 + ' €')
         $('.overallprice').html(total1)
    });

    $('input').click(function() {
        var total2 = 0;
        $('.option12:checked').each(function() {
            total2 += parseInt($(this).val());
         });

         $('.total2').html(total2 + ' €')
         $('.overallprice').html(total2)
    });
});
```

Comment: What's the problem ?

Comment: why there are two click handler for same `input` selector? could you please post your html also?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are registering click handler for each total section and putting overall price equal to last calculated total instead of sum of total. You can have single click handler and calculate total. Do sum of total spans and put it in overall, see below code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
    var total = 0;
    var $parent = $(this).closest('ul');
    $parent.find('input:checked').each(function() {
      total += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    //find span having class start with total by using start with selector
    $parent.find('span[class^=total]').html(total + ' €');

    var overallPrice = 0;
    $('span[class^=total]').each(function() {
     //span having class start with total
      overallPrice += parseInt($(this).html().replace(' €',''));
    });
    $('.overallprice').html(overallPrice)
  });
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qw6stm4p/18/)**

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Also thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 0):

something like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/bmhs35oh/1/)?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul').each(function(){
        var $thisUl = $(this);
        $thisUl.find('input').change(function(){
            var total = 0;
            $thisUl.find('input:checked').each(function() {
                total += parseInt($(this).val());
            });
            $thisUl.find('li:last span').html(total + ' €')
        });
    });

    $('input').change(function(){
        var overAllPrice = 0;
        $('input:checked').each(function(){
            overAllPrice += parseInt($(this).val());
        })
        $('.overallprice').html(overAllPrice);
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qw6stm4p/9/embedded/result/)

verify the functions.
Actually the concept is to get all checkboxes which is checked and then sum of the total value.

```
function calTotal() {
    var totalprice = 0;
    $('#form input:checked').each(function() {
        totalprice += parseInt($(this).val());
    });
    $('.overallprice').html(totalprice);
}
```

You need to call this function for every input handler you have attached

Answer (score 0):

Just replace this script to your jsfiddle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').click(function() {
        var total1 = 0;
        $('.option1:checked').each(function() {
            total1 += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('.total').html(total1 + ' €')
        $('.overallprice').html(total1);

        var total2 = 0;
        $('.option12:checked').each(function() {
            total2 += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('.total2').html(total2 + ' €')
        $('.overallprice').html(total2);

        var total3 = 0;
        $('.option13:checked').each(function() {
            total3 += parseInt($(this).val());
        });
        $('.total3').html(total3 + ' €');
        $('.overallprice').html( (total1 + total2 + total3) + ' €');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/qw6stm4p/19/)**

- Keep a single `click event handler` for all the `checkbox`
- Identify which `checkbox` was clicked and update its relative total accordingly
- Perform a separate `each` loop for all the `checkbox` to update `total`.

Your updated JS would be:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox]').click(function() {
    //one click event attached to all checkbox
    var parent = $(this).closest('ul'); //get its closest ul element which contains remaining checkbox
    var total1 = 0;//keep one variable for total to add it to each checkboxes total
    var overAll = 0;//one for overall total
    parent.find($('input[type=checkbox]:checked')).each(function() {
      total1 += parseInt($(this).val());
      //each loop on clicked checkbox's siblings
    })
    parent.find('.total').text(total1 + " €");//update total on clicked checkbox hierarchy
    $('input[type=checkbox]:checked').each(function() {
      overAll += parseInt($(this).val());
      //each loop on all the checkbox which are checked to get overall total
    });
    $('.overallprice').html(overAll)
  })
})
```